# Selecting rows programmatically in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I want to select row of previously selected rows after some event my code is as below.

```
int currentRow = dgvIcbSubsInfo.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
//code to execute
dgvIcbSubsInfo.Rows[currentRow].Selected = true;
```

after executing the code the preview will be as below. but i need to get the symbol `>` in id = 1272741 (blue selection) and not in 1272737

[image]

Comment: Dude , question is hard to understand , not clear enough!

Comment: > means selection arrow at first rows

Comment: The problem is that the row index of the selected item changed (e.g. after sorting or requerying the data source).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Probably you might have taken a look at the [DataGridView.CurrentRow Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx), which is a read-only property:

> Gets the row containing the current cell.

But in the remarks section, there is written:

> To change the current row, you must set the [`CurrentCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) property to a
>   cell in the desired row.

Also, from the [DataGridView.CurrentCell Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx), we find out that:

> When you change the value of this property, the SelectionChanged event
>   occurs before the CurrentCellChanged event. Any SelectionChanged event
>   handler accessing the CurrentCell property at this time will get its
>   previous value.

So, there is no need that you actually select the `currentRow` becasue it will be selected when you set the `CurrentCell` value (unless you have some code to be executed inside the current scope between the `SelectionChanged` and `CurrentCellChanged` events). Try this:

```
//dgvIcbSubsInfo.Rows[currentRow].Selected = true;
dgvIcbSubsInfo.CurrentCell = dgvIcbSubsInfo.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0];
```

Comment: That's a really nice digging in to the code and comments, as well as a thorough explanation of how you got your answer. Thank you Alex!

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish to highlight the row. Please try following code, I think it might help:

```
Color color = dgv.Rows[prevRowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor;
dgv.Rows[curRowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = color;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to change the current row.  Since the OP is a little unclear as to what row should be the new row, my example simply shows moving from the current row to the previous row (if there is a previous row).  The first line of code is optional.  You can also hardcode col to 0 (or some other column) to use a fixed column if you don't want to use FullRowSelect.

```
dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
int row = dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
int firstRow = dataGridView.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.None);
if (row != firstRow)
{
  row--;
  int col = dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
  dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView[col, row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here wanting to learn how to programmatically select rows in a DataGridView control.  Here is how to select the top row in your DataGridView control named dg1 and "click" it:

```
dg1.Rows[0].Selected = true;                      

dg1_RowHeaderMouseClick(null, null);
```

This then calls the following event which is expecting one selected row.

```
private void dg1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {                        
        var selectedRows = dg1.SelectedRows;

        // Make sure we have a single row selected
        int count = selectedRows.Count;

        if (count == 1)
        {                
            tbAssemblyName.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();                
        }
    }
```

I had everything working when the user clicked the row they wanted.  When there was only one record to choose from I wanted to "click" it for the user.